# Using an ArrayList to display values from another class

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to make a to do list that asks you to enter your tasks one by one then display them in order (as in 1. task1, 2. task 2, 3. task 3 etc). But when it displays the tasks it comes back as "0. null" one time instead of listing any of the tasks entered. Here is the script I am using:

1st class

```
package todolist;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ToDoList1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ArrayList<ToDoList2> list = new ArrayList<ToDoList2>();
        System.out.println("Time to make a digital to-do list!");

        ToDoList2 n = new ToDoList2();
        list.add(n);

        System.out.println(ToDoList2.name + "'s to-do list");
        System.out.println(ToDoList2.i + ". " + ToDoList2.l);

        for(ToDoList2 enhanced : list)
        {
            System.out.println(ToDoList2.i + ". " + ToDoList2.m);
        }
    }
}
```

2nd class

```
package todolist;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ToDoList2 {
    public static String name;
    public static int i;
    public static String l;
    public static String m;

    {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("First type your name to identify your list in case you lose it");
        name = s.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Make sure to type \"end\" when you are finished");    
        System.out.println("Type in the first item on your to-do list");
        String l = s.nextLine();
    }

    public ToDoList2() 
    {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);    
        for(int i = 1; i == i; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Type in the next item for your to-do list");
            String m = s.nextLine();
            if("end".equals(m))
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: not clear, why you have a list with just an element? I am talking abt *list* in the 1st class

Comment: In the constructor of the second class, *ToDoList2* , you read strings from the scanner but you save nowhere. What's for?

Comment: i save the Strings from the scanner in the second class to the variable 'm'

Comment: You store it each time as m! But you don't use it. Every time you create a new String *m* but you don't use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) Given that each ToDoList2 object is a separate task, I'm not sure why you've made the object class members static?

b) In your ToDoList2 constructor, you've got a for loop that introduces a local variable i which hides the ToDoList2 member variable i. You'd do well to change one of the variable names.

c) In your ToDoList2 constructor, you've got a for loop which is assigning a string returned by the Scanner to a local variable m. Are you sure you want m to be a local variable or do you actually want to assign the returned string to the member variable, m? I'm thinking the latter since the member variable m is never being assigned a value which explains why the code is printing out null.

d) When writing code, it is good practice to use meaningful variable names. Using names like i is OK as an index in a loop but in all other circumstances, you should go for something more descriptive that tells the reader what the variable is storing.

e) Consider making all your ToDoList2 member variables private (and final if possible). Add a print function to the ToDoList2 class to print out the task details. A key principle is Object Oriented Programming is to hide the internals of a class.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is not correct. ToDoList2 scanning item list from standard input but not storing it. You should do as follow

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

class TodoList {

    public static String name;

    List<String> tasks;

    public TodoList(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.tasks = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addTask(String task) {
        this.tasks.add(task);
    }

    public String toString() {
        int i = 1;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (String task : tasks) {
            stringBuilder.append(i + ". " + task);
            stringBuilder.append("\n");
            i++;
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("First type your name to identify your list in case you lose it");
        String name = s.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Make sure to type \"end\" when you are finished");
        System.out.println("Type in the first item on your to-do list");

        TodoList todoList = new TodoList(name);

        String task = null;
        while (!(task = s.nextLine()).equals("end")) {
            todoList.addTask(task);
            System.out.println("Type in the next item for your to-do list");
        }

        System.out.println(todoList);

    }


}
```